# How do you obtain an array of vlookup values without an extra column in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list and a lookup table. The list will be in column A and the lookup table will be in columns C and D. Each cell in column C contains text and is unique. Column D has a corresponding value for each element of column C. Column A contains an unsorted list with duplicates of the text from column C but nothing outside of column C. An easy example is shown below

[image: Simple Example]

What I ultimately want is an array that contains the corresponding values looked up from the table for all of column A. So in this example I want

```
{1,2,1,2,2,2,1,1,2}
```

I know this can be accomplished by using

```
=vlookup(B9,$C$1:$D$2,2,FALSE)
```

in each cell of column B and grab the column as an array {$B$1:$B$9}. However, I need to skip the middle man and omit having anything in another column as this needs to be performed on various lookup tables simultaneous but not connected, i.e. not a multiple lookup, I just need to look at the same list A under a different set of corresponding values D.

I'm at a complete loss, it seems so simple but I've been trying for hours and going in circles. I recall reading that you can't output vlookup to an array and I didn't have much luck trying to use match either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to continue to use VLOOKUP:

`VLOOKUP(T(IF(1,+A1:A9)),C1:D2,2,0)`

where T is employed here since the values in A1:A9 are text, not numeric (otherwise we would use instead N - a range containing mixed datatypes would require a different approach).

http://excelxor.com/2014/09/05/index-returning-an-array-of-values/

Regards

Comment: Works great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your array with the following use of the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) in its **array form**. Since your lookup table is in the same orientation as the values in A1:A9, you must [TRANSPOSE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRANSPOSE-function-ED039415-ED8A-4A81-93E9-4B6DFAC76027) A1:A9 to achieve the cyclic array processing.

As an array formula¹,

```
=INDEX((TRANSPOSE(A1:A9)=C1:C2)*(D1:D2), , )
```

This can be proved in a single cell by wrapping the array result in a [SUM function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sum-function-0761ed42-45aa-4267-a9fc-a88a058c1a57) which will total the elements of the array.

```
=SUM(INDEX((TRANSPOSE(A1:A9)=C1:C2)*(D1:D2), , ))
```

... which returns **14**.

[image: index_array]
              <sup>INDEX function in Array Form</sup>

---

¹ <sub>Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. Once entered into the first cell correctly, they can be filled or copied down or right just like any other formula. Try and reduce your full-column references to ranges more closely representing the extents of your actual data. Array formulas chew up calculation cycles logarithmically so it is good practise to narrow the referenced ranges to a minimum. See [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) for more information.</sub>

Comment: Does this not return a 2-D array? {1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0;0,2,0,2,2,2,0,0,2} Check with product as well; it returns 0.